# Defining max and min values for a variable in C++

Tags: c++, variables

I'm working on a project, and was curious about if there's an easy way to define custom max and min values for a double variable. At the moment, there's a quite large if-else if block handling this, but my question is can I do something in the variable's declaration so that these checks are unneeded?

Comment: Is this variable a private member of a struct/class? If so, you can use a technique known as a **class invariant**. Otherwise, you'd want something called **dependant types**, which C++ does not have language-level support for.

Comment: @Frank The class invariant stuff is what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> was curious about if there's an easy way to define custom max and min values for a double variable.

Since C++17, there is standard library function `std::clamp` that you can use to set out of-bound value to maximum / minimum depending on which boundary it exceeded.

If you need some other behaviour for out-of-bound values, or need to support older C++, the you can use if-else to check whether a new value is within the allowed bounds.

> At the moment, there's a quite large if-else if block handling this,

Two conditionals should be sufficient. One for upper bound, another for lower.